# Cannot boot after installing ubuntu on lenovo x120e

Tags: grub2, boot-failure, uefi

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on my x120e using amd64 alternate iso image.
The installation went fine, but it is having issues while booting after a successful installation, it says - "No Operating System Found".
I followed the instruction at - help.ubuntu.com/community/X120e#Installation to purge grub-efi and installed grub-pc, even then I couldn't boot into ubuntu.(got the same "No Operating System Found")
This is the file from boot-repair with this setup - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/926556/

Then I asked in #ubuntu and they suggested me to create a bios-boot partition, I was not very comfortable with the solution they had suggested but gave it a try anyhow.
I re-sized my initial partition and made 4 MB free space in the beginning of the partition and had set the flag bios_grub.
Re-installed ubuntu 11.10 this time using amd64 desktop iso image file.
Installation went fine as before but finally this time also the system didn't boot, it gave the same - "No Operating System Found" message.

In BIOS I have the settings as to use both (Legacy and UEFI) and with UEFI tried first.
This is the boot-repair file from my latest setup - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/926761

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found that all these trouble were due to the GPT partition written to my disk instead of MBR and I had replaced grub-efi with grub-pc. Grub was looking for the bios_boot partition since my GPT string was telling it the system doesn't use EFI, I had setup a 4 MB bios boot partition and it didn't worked even after repeated attempts trying out things with GParted and book-repair.

I started with a fresh install, but this time I had disabled the UEFI support in BIOS before the installation and only enabled the Legacy option.
This time the system had no chance to mix up things and I got my system to boot after the installation.

ps: I installed using the alternate amd64 iso, since desktop amd64 iso stuck in between installation.

Answer (score 0):

Filed the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1040320